# Running into ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when checking multiple links

Tags: php, http

I want to write a small PHP script which checks the existence of files on a server.

The files URLs have the following format:

`http://update.example.com/Files/Updates/7.25.2.128/application7_25_2_128_de_FullInstallerx64.exe`

Now I want to loop through the version numbers and check if the file exists.

```php
function checkAllUrls() {
  $revisionNumber = 25;
  $minorNumber = 2;
  $buildNumber = 128;

  for ($x = $buildNumber; $x > 0; $x--) {

     file_put_contents('log.txt', "Checking Build: $x", FILE_APPEND);
     $combinedUrl = 'http://update.example.com/Files/Updates/6.' . $revisionNumber . '.' .  $minorNumber . '.' .  $x . '/application7_' . $revisionNumber . '_' .  $minorNumber . '_' .  $x . '_de_FullInstallerx64.exe';

   $urlHeaders = @get_headers($combinedUrl);

   if(!$urlHeaders || $urlHeaders[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
        $exists = "no";
        file_put_contents('log.txt', "\n" . $combinedUrl . " - " . "does not exist. \n", FILE_APPEND);
    } else {
        $exists = "yes";
        file_put_contents('log.txt', "\n" . $combinedUrl . " - " . "exists. \n", FILE_APPEND);
        
    }
  sleep(3);
  }
}
```

The problem is, that even if using `sleep()` with 3 seconds, the links / files are not checked after a couple of links.

Afterwards I cannot open any of the valid links in my browser any more getting `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` in return. At first I was afraid, that I kind of crashed the server, but accessing via VPN still lets me download the file.

Can anybody explain to my, why this is happening and how I can avoid this behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some bots protection system probably. If it so, then You should use some proxys, to reduce detection.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your problem don't use multiple request. Try this multiple curl request method.

```
function checkAllUrls() {
    $revisionNumber = 25;
    $minorNumber = 2;
    $buildNumber = 128;

    $multiCurl = curl_multi_init();
    $curlArray = array();
  
    for ($x = $buildNumber; $x > 0; $x--) {

        $combinedUrl = 'http://update.example.com/Files/Updates/6.' . $revisionNumber . '.' .  $minorNumber . '.' .  $x . '/application7_' . $revisionNumber . '_' .  $minorNumber . '_' .  $x . '_de_FullInstallerx64.exe';

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $combinedUrl);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

        curl_multi_add_handle($multiCurl,$curl);
        $curlArray[] = ['curl' => $curl, 'build' => $x] ;
    }

    $i = NULL;
    do {
        $x = curl_multi_exec($multiCurl, $i);
    } while ($i > 0);

    foreach ($curlArray as $k => $v) {
        file_put_contents('log.txt', "Checking Build: ".$v['build'], FILE_APPEND);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($v['curl'], CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        $combinedUrl = curl_getinfo($v['curl'], CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
        if($httpCode === 404) {
            $exists = "no";
            file_put_contents('log.txt', "\n" . $combinedUrl . " - " . "does not exist. \n", FILE_APPEND);
        } else {
            $exists = "yes";
            file_put_contents('log.txt', "\n" . $combinedUrl . " - " . "exists. \n", FILE_APPEND);
            
        }
        curl_multi_remove_handle($multiCurl, $v['curl']);
    }

    curl_multi_close($multiCurl);
  }
```